# Inserts an additional character when two strings appended. Why?

Tags: c#, string, c#-4.0, salesforce, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to connect visual studio and salesforce. In the visual studio I have to build the url to request the token.The url built as a `stringbuilder` object using `Append()` function.I get the token when the url used in the rest console. But the url generated in the visual studio inserts an additional character between password and security token.The extra character is only seen when I choose the ANSI encoding.

```
StringBuilder body = new StringBuilder();
    //body.Append("code=" + code + "&");
    body.Append("grant_type=password&");
    body.Append("client_id=" +clientID +"&");
    body.Append("client_secret="+clientSecret+"&");
    body.Append("username="+username+"&");
    body.Append("password=" + pass);
    body.Append(security_token);

        string result = HttpPost(URI, body.ToString());
```

/*************************************code of HttpPost()*************

```
System.Net.WebRequest req = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(URI);
    req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    req.Method = "POST";

    // Add parameters to post
    byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Parameters);
    req.ContentLength = data.Length;
    System.IO.Stream os = req.GetRequestStream();
    os.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    os.Close();

    // Do the post and get the response.
    System.Net.WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
    if (resp == null) return null;
    System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
    return sr.ReadToEnd().Trim();
```

Running the above code inserts an additional character between the `password` and the `security_token`, resulting in a `System.Net.WebException`. The exception occurs when getting the response. Can anyone tell me the reason for this?

Comment: Please provide a minimal test case source code.

Comment: The code looks fine. Your code does not show what is wrong with the resulting string.

Comment: @wilx if the password is abc123 and security token is hjasy2s23wh,then the appended string is abc123?hjasy2s23wh.

Comment: output the values of the variables (pass, security_token) and you will most probably notice that the additional characters are already in there; the code above doesn't "magically" insert some characters. Show how these variables get filled, the problem probably lies there.

Answer (score 1):

You have not provided code which throws error. Since you have mentioned the string is a URL, so i am guessing extra character is added by the browser. So i am suggesting to use UrlEncode to encode your URL. And use UrlDecode to read the original URL back.

```
HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode(body.ToString());
```

To know more about UrlEncode visit [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)